# SSIS: Selecting multiple input columns and mapping them to their respective destination in one action

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

Can selecting multiple available input columns and mapping them to their respective destination be done in one action!?!?! Instead of selecting 1 input at a time! I've tried holding control and the Shift key to select multiple ones and drag them over, but only the one you click on copies over. This is a huge time waster for tables that have multiple columns and for whatever reason SSIS doesn't automatically map them over, even with the columns names matching!  I'm in SSIS 2008 R2 BTW.

The image below is just an example to illustrate what I'm talking about, it is not my personal example:
[image]
<sub>(source: [ggpht.com](https://lh4.ggpht.com/-OPjd_mDIT7I/UWEMuKqmYXI/AAAAAAAAAIs/7uzV8eHs4R8/clip_image006_thumb%25255B2%25255D.jpg?imgmax=800))</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, you can Right-click in the column names area on the diagram & Select "Map Items By Matching Names"

[image]
<sub>(source: [hoegaerden.be](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/wp-content/uploads/image652.png))</sub>